# What does the [] symbol mean in this context?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

According to a text given by my teacher, "given any partition $P$ of $X$, we can induce the natural projection of $X$ onto $P$, $p$ : $X \rightarrow P$ satisfying $p$ : $x \mapsto [x$]." What does the [] symbol mean in this context, and how can I visualize the map?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this context, $[x]$ is the equivalence class of $x$. So, for instance, if $X=\Bbb Z$ and the equivalence relation $\sim$ is defined by $a\sim b$ if and only if $a$ and $b$ have the same parity, then $[1]=\{\text{odd integers}\}$ and $[8]=\{\text{even integers}\}$.

Answer (score 0):

In this context, $[x]$ denotes the equivalence class of $x$, a.k.a., the element of $P$ that contains $x$. To visualize the map, let $X$ be the set of integers and suppose $P$ consists of two sets, $O = \{n \in X \;|\; n \text{ is odd}\}$ and $E = \{n \in X \;|\; n \text{ is even}\}$. Then $P$ is a partition of $X$ and the function $p:X \rightarrow P$ sends every even integer to $E$ and every odd integer to $O$.